При запуске контейнера Docker выводится ошибка: NoClassDefFoundError
Есть многомодульный проект Maven Java c главным модулем MavenProject, в котором заключены модули: startApp (находится точка входа App.java), mr-231, mr-231-3. При сборке Dockerfile (находится в корневой MavenProject) выводится следующая ошибка: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/example/searadar/mr231/station/Mr231StationType
2024-06-09T01:46:44.947316456Z  at org.example.App.main(App.java:41)
2024-06-09T01:46:44.948306086Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.searadar.mr231.station.Mr231StationType
2024-06-09T01:46:44.948361888Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
2024-06-09T01:46:44.948573194Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
2024-06-09T01:46:44.950044738Z  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) <br><br>

Конфиг Dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-8 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/startApp/target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Думаю, что ошибка возникает с проблемой в зависимостях самого проекта, поэтому вот все pom файлы проекта:
MavenProject/pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenProjectSearadar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>startApp</module>
        <module>mr-231</module>
        <module>mr-231-3</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

MavenProject/startApp/pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>startApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenProjectSearadar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>mr-231-3</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>mr-231</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

MavenProject/mr-231/pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>mr-231</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Interaction module with Radar MR-231 system</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenProjectSearadar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

MavenProject/mr231-3/pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>mr-231-3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Interaction module with Radar MR-231-3 system</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenProjectSearadar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Нужно в образ положить все зависимости для startApp.jar, а до этого их нужно собрать и указать в манифесте. Для этого есть несколько плагинов, например
maven-assembly-plugin - позволяет скопировать зависимости в отдельную папку
maven-shade-plugin - собирает fat-jar (1 jar со всеми зависимостями внутри), что в случаем docker избыточно

Использовал maven shade, помогло. Пытался с maven assembly, но не получилось правильно установить, плагин просто не видно, хотя jar был установлен в корректную директорию
